# include css in magento2 for custom theme

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, javascript, css

I am trying to include custom css and js in custom theme and should come on all pages.

I have tried [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html#fedg_css-in-themes_xml) from the Magento DevDocs, but I can't make it right and it's not showing. Please help me.

Comment: file css or js just in custom theme/web/css/file-css-name.css then refresh cache. maybe help you.

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ` did you deploy content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For keep css and js in all pages you have to customize `default_head_blocks.xml` file. set file,

`magento2/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` file

Put inside `<head>` tag,

```
<css src="css/styles.css"/> 
<script src="js/custom.js"/>
```

Add your css file inside,

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/css/styles.css
```

Add your custom js

```
 app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/custom.js
```

Remove cache folder and try.

Its now working in all pages of site.

Comment: Thanks. Although i have tried this and i was not aware that it will convert into .min.css. Actually it was there morning also. I was looking for my css. :)

Comment: also if we are editing the css, always its rendering from pub static folder and every time we need to refresh to see the css change in frontend. Is there any possible way to see css change every refresh of page?

Comment: apply command php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer && php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: after done above command , deploy theme using, php magento setup:static-content:deploy, may be solve your issue.

Comment: I Found This Magento2Site\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml

Answer (score 0):

When I updated my theme, my css files got deleted from app/design/bluesky/frontend/theme-name/web/css/custom.css and also the path from the
default_head_block_xml.