# How to add custom styles to Bought theme in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, theme, css, less-css, styles

I have applied a free theme on my **magento2** store that don't have **css** file to edit custom styles. But it has less files like below,

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/source/_theme.less, _custom.less
```

I tried below link to create custom theme in magneto2.

[include css in magento2 for custom theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102126/include-css-in-magento2-for-custom-theme).

Where i added `styles.css` inside

`web/css` folder like below and whenever i add styles it affects on the website.

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/styles.css
```

But how to edit .less files to make work like the above one?
Please anyone suggest how to work on css styles to the purchased themes?

Comment: so your confusion is how to work in less like _custom.less or you want to create new custom css?

Comment: confusion with working _custom.less files? I need detail explanation on both please.

Comment: you can check these answers that will help https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588,  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento recomand to use less for better configuration and optimization, for that you need to use **_extend.less** .

Create it to this path:

```
app\design\frontend\vendor-name\theme-name\Magento_Theme\web\css\source\_extend.less
```

For better understanding you can review this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html)

Install Grunt after doing this by this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)

Run grunt commands or the deploy command to see your changes on front side.